# Create database with Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've stumbled upon a problem where I want to create a database using code first with Entity Framework. In recent projects I have not used EF to connect to my database successfully but now something is wrong.

I have created my app.config file with following content:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="HomeCinema" 
     connectionString="Data Source= {MY SERVER NAME IN MSSQL};Initial
     Catalog=HomeCinema;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I assume Data Source shall contain what I log on with on my SQL Server.

When I try to create the database with my classes in the project, I use update-database -verbose to create it in the Package Manager Console and I target the correct project.

And here it says when I use the update-database -verbose: 
Target database is: 'HomeCinema' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention)

The DataSource here is different than what I have specified in the App.config file. I assume there is something wrong there but just can't figure it out.

I have not done this way before and its uncharted territory to me that I wish to fix, but can't seem to grasp why it happens or how to fix it.

Hopefully I have described the matter clearly but please ask if there is something missing.

Would highly appreciate it if I could recieve some guidelines or some tips to how to solve this problem or if there is another way to go about to create the database.

My DbContext class:

```
public class HomeCinemaContext : DbContext
{
    public HomeCinemaContext() 
        : base("HomeCinema")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<HomeCinemaContext>(null);
    }
    #region Entity Sets 
    public IDbSet<User> UserSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Role> RoleSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<UserRole> UserRoleSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Customer> CustomerSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Movie> MovieSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Genre> GenreSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Stock> StockSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Rental> RentalSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Error> ErrorSet { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Can you post your DbContext?

Comment: Updated the question with my DbContext now.

Comment: When executing the command, is the active project the project containing the displayed configuration file?

Comment: Yes it is CodeCaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two projects, let's say a Class Library and a Web Application referencing it. You need to add the connection from app.config to the web.config in your web application.

When you target the class library with the Package Manager Console you are telling VS to look for a DbContext defined in that assembly, but the connection string is from the main Web Application.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now, database up and running!